# How to simplify sympy vectors?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, simplify

I am doing some symbolic vector calculations using `sympy`, but I can't simplify the arguments of the vector class in a proper way. Consider this code:

```py
from sympy.physics.mechanics import ReferenceFrame, dot, cross
from sympy import symbols, sin, cos, simplify

alpha, theta, l = symbols('alpha theta l')

def Rodrigues(v, k, angle):
    return cos(angle) * v + cross(k, v) * sin(angle) + k * dot(k, v) * (1- cos(angle))

N = ReferenceFrame('N')
P0 = -l * N.y

P2 = Rodrigues(
    Rodrigues(P0, -N.z, alpha), 
    Rodrigues(N.x, -N.z, alpha), 
    theta)
```

which returns:

trying the `simplify(P2)` I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'

which I think is because the `simplify` requires a `sympy` expression object. trying the `dir(P2)` there is a `simplify` method which returns:

```
<bound method Vector.simplify of - l*sin(alpha)*cos(theta)*N.x - l*cos(alpha)*cos(theta)*N.y + (-l*sin(alpha)**2 - l*cos(alpha)**2)*sin(theta)*N.z>
```

which I have no idea what it is! trying the `P2.args` I get:

```
[(Matrix([
  [                       -l*sin(alpha)*cos(theta)],
  [                       -l*cos(alpha)*cos(theta)],
  [(-l*sin(alpha)**2 - l*cos(alpha)**2)*sin(theta)]]), N)]
```

which is a 1D List of a 2D tuple with a nested 3x1 `sympy` Matrix! I don't know whos choice was to make the vector class so obscure, but now I can simplify the last element with `simplify(P2.args[0][0][2])` and change the function to:

```py
def Rodrigues(v, k, angle):
    tmpVec = cos(angle) * v + cross(k, v) * sin(angle) + k * dot(k, v) * (1- cos(angle))
    tmpFrame = tmpVec.args[0][1]
    return simplify(tmpVec.args[0][0][0]) * tmpFrame.x + simplify(tmpVec.args[0][0][1]) * tmpFrame.y + simplify(tmpVec.args[0][0][2]) * tmpFrame.z
```

which to me seems like a very bad solution.

I was wondering if you could help me know if there is a more Pythonic way to do this. For example, force `sympy` to simplify all expressions by default. Or maybe I'm using the `vector.simplify` method in a wrong way? Thanks for your support in advance.

P.S. [Rodrigues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) rotation formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `print(P2.simplify)` you need to call this method like `print(P2.simplify())`. After that you will get `- l*sin(alpha)*cos(theta)*N.x - l*cos(alpha)*cos(theta)*N.y - l*sin(theta)*N.z` as output which is the same to last version of your `def Rodrigues`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to force sympy to simplify all vectors by default:

```py
from sympy.physics.vector import Vector
Vector.simp = True
```

more info [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/api/classes.html)